# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProductOptions()

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.3

Can anyone help? I'm having this error in *namespace/sales/order/view/order_id/4/*:
[image]

Thank a lot!

Comment: add  block code of Customer history module

Comment: @MSA could you say more detail? Thanks

Comment: @MSA thanks for your help. It working.

Answer (score 0):

The object(like product) on which you are calling getProductOptions() method is null or not initialised. Thats why you are getting such error. So you can check whether object is initialised properly or not.